# How to switch between the Available/Paired bluetooth device in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, runtime-error, bluetoothadapter

We all know how to show the paired device list but my question is how we can switch to our preferable bluetooth headset from the list. I only want this option for mobile to headset. Can anybody kindly give me some solution in this problem? I have used the normal code from " Android Developer " site.

The Language is Java.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please don't paste the same text multiple times. If the site asks you to enter more text, that's not the solution.